# expandable/contractable columns with 100% width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Trying to make 5 divs ( acting as columns 100% height, 20% width ) contractible and expandable with jquery on mouse hover. I got this part working to a degree but last column is bugging and creating strange white gap before going back to original position. see attached fiddle as its hard to explain. I want to get this working without last column freaking out on me.

```
<body>
<div class="columnContainer">
    <section class="mainColumn columnOne" class="">

    </section>
    <section class="mainColumn columnTwo" class="">

    </section>
    <section class="mainColumn columnThree" class="">

    </section>
    <section class="mainColumn columnFour" class="">

    </section>
    <section class="mainColumn columnFive" class="">

    </section>
</div>


<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="js/jq-ui.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="js/playgroundjs.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

```
.columnContainer{
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
display: block;
left: 0;
top: 0;
```

}

```
$(".mainColumn").click(function(){
if ( $(this).hasClass("large") ){
     $(this).animate({width:"20%"},300), $(".mainColumn").animate({width:"20%"});
     $(this).removeClass("large");
}
else {
     $(this).animate({width:"40%"},300);
     $(this).removeClass("mainColumn"), $(".mainColumn").animate({width:"15%"},300);
     $(this).addClass("mainColumn");
     $(this).addClass("large");
}
```

});

http://jsfiddle.net/LxmRx/

Comment: All answers are very good, I appreciate the support. perfect example of many ways to skin a cat I suppose :) Ill be honest Im not very familiar with JS or css transitions so im using these answers as a learning curve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a CSS-only solution: http://jsfiddle.net/CWrU2/.  I've trimmed down your code for clarity.  Setting `display` to `table` and `table-cell` took care of the white space that would appear due to animation during hovering.

Using CSS performance improves by about 50% (although, that is a rough estimate).

HTML:

```
<div class="columnContainer">
    <section></section>
    <section></section>
    <section></section>
    <section></section>
    <section></section>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body, html, .columnContainer{
    height: 100%;
}

.columnContainer {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

.columnContainer > section {
    width: 20%;
    display: table-cell;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.3s linear;
    transition: width 0.3s linear;
}

.columnContainer:hover > section:hover {
    width: 40%;
}

.columnContainer:hover > section {
    width: 15%;
}

.columnContainer > section:nth-of-type(1) {
    background-color: rgba(200,200,250, 0.5);
}
.columnContainer > section:nth-of-type(2) {
    background-color: rgba(200,250,200, 0.5);
}
.columnContainer > section:nth-of-type(3) {
    background-color: rgba(250,200,200, 0.5);
}
.columnContainer > section:nth-of-type(4) {
    background-color: rgba(200,225,225, 0.5);
}
.columnContainer > section:nth-of-type(5) {
    background-color: rgba(225,200,225, 0.5);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, could you explain a few things for me though? What exactly does changing the display to table and table-cell do ? And also what code makes all other sections go to 15% width when one section goes to 40% width? Is it because of the order in which you laid out the styles ?

Comment: First, table-cells (inside a table) are automatically stacked horizontally.  Second, table-cells automatically fill the table height.  Third, table cells are displayed with "consideration" of other table cells.  This is why during animation you won't see white gaps in between "columns."  Here's a fiddle that uses floating: http://jsfiddle.net/CWrU2/2/.  Launch it, and move mouse pointer quickly horizontally across columns.  The white space should appear towards the end.

Comment: Technically, the setting of width of 20% is not necessary.  Setting it, however, helps with the smoothness of transitions, because the starting point is explicitly set.  Regarding your question about the resizing effect.  It's all in the selector specificity.  The declaration that comes with this selector `.columnContainer:hover > section` sets the width for every section to 15%.  However, the width for one of the sections that is hovered gets overridden to 40%, because this selector `.columnContainer:hover > section:hover` is more specific.

Comment: If you are interested to get a more practical insight into this topic and other topics, you are welcome to check out my book - "Functional CSS: Dynamic HTML without JavaScript" - on amazon.  It's case-based and offers a good insight into HTML and CSS.  Cheers and happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust your widths with js:

```
$(".columnContainer").on("mouseenter", "section", function(e){
    $('.mainColumn').width('15%');
    $(e.target).width('40%')
});

$(".columnContainer").on("mouseleave", "section", function(e){
    $('.mainColumn').width('20%');
});
```

And use css for the animation:

```
.mainColumn {
    -webkit-transition: width .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: width .3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: width .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: width .3s ease-in-out;
}
```

Here's a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/dubbs/6GPaA/

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the best answers are the simplest. Depending on your needs, adding this may work just fine.

```
body {
    background-color: rgba(225,200,225, 1);
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LxmRx/2/

Answer (score 0):

This was a brilliant post that taught me many things. I modified the above fiddle to create expandable buttons that show text on hover.

```
    <div class="columnContainer">
        <section><div class="div1" style="width:50%; float:left">test</div><div class="div2" style="width:50%; float:left">test</div></section>
        <section><div class="div3" style="width:50%; float:left">test</div><div class="div4" style="width:50%; float:left">test</div></section>
</div>

.div2 {
    display: none;
}

.columnContainer:hover > section:nth-of-type(1):hover .div2 {
    display: block;
}

.div4 {
    display: none;
}

.columnContainer:hover > section:nth-of-type(2):hover .div4 {
    display: block;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/CWrU2/24/

I'm really grateful to you all and I hope my additions will be useful to someone!